# Let $e_0$ be minimal projection, why $E_{e_0}$ is a Hilbert space?

Tags: banach-algebras

‎A nonzero element $e \in \mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$ is called a projection‎, ‎if it is‎
 ‎self adjoint and  idempotent‎. ‎In addition‎, ‎if $e\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})e = \mathbb{C}e$ then‎, ‎it is called a minimal projection‎.
‎Suppose that $e_0\in \mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$ is a minimal projection‎
 ‎and  $E_{e_0} =\lbrace  xe_0‎ : ‎x\in E\rbrace$‎.

Why $E_{e_0}$‎
 ‎is a Hilbert space with the inner product $(xe_0‎, ‎ye_0) = tr(\langle xe_0‎, ‎ye_0\rangle)$ for all $x‎, ‎y\in E$ ‎?